# About function with Manipulate and order of evaluation

Tags: functions, manipulate, evaluation

I have many problems to understand how mathematica evaluates `Manipulate[]` when I use function before or inside `Manipulate[]` .

Could you give me a practise, a method to work with functions and `Manipulate[]`.

This is my code :

```
TimeConstrained[
 A16[poly_] := 
  PolyhedronData[poly, "VertexCoordinates"][[16]] // FullSimplify;
 A7[poly_] := 
  PolyhedronData[poly, "VertexCoordinates"][[7]] // FullSimplify;
 S1[r1_] := Sphere[A16[poly][[1]], r1] // FullSimplify;
 Spoly[poly_] := PolyhedronData[poly, "Circumsphere"];
 polyw[poly_] := PolyhedronData[poly];
 A167[poly_] := 
  RegionIntersection[HalfLine[{0, 0, 0}, A16[poly] + A7[poly]], 
    Spoly[poly]] // FullSimplify;
 C16 = RegionIntersection[S1[r1], Spoly[poly]];
 reg = Region[A167[poly]];

 Manipulate[
  Show[
   reg,
   Graphics3D[{{Opacity[o], S1[r1], Spoly[poly]}, polyw[poly]}]],
  {{r1, 1/10}, 0, 3}, {{o, 0.1}, 0, 1}, {{poly, "Dodecahedron"}, 
   PolyhedronData[]},
  Initialization :> (poly := "Dodecahedron")],
 30]
```

UPDATE

I modified my code with the advice of Bill and I corrected 2 errors ,

now It works !

```
Manipulate[
  A16[poly_] := 
   PolyhedronData[poly, "VertexCoordinates"][[16]] // FullSimplify;
  A7[poly_] := 
   PolyhedronData[poly, "VertexCoordinates"][[7]] // FullSimplify;
  S1[r1_] := Sphere[A16[poly], r1] // FullSimplify;
  Spoly[poly_] := PolyhedronData[poly, "Circumsphere"];
  polyw[poly_] := PolyhedronData[poly];
  A167[poly_] := 
   RegionIntersection[HalfLine[{0, 0, 0}, A16[poly] + A7[poly]], 
     Spoly[poly]] // FullSimplify;
  C16 = RegionIntersection[S1[r1], Spoly[poly]];
  reg = Region[A167[poly]];
  Show[
   reg,
   Graphics3D[{{Opacity[o], S1[r1], Spoly[poly]}}],
   polyw[poly]],
  {{r1, 1/10}, 0, 3}, {{o, 0.1}, 0, 1}, {{poly, "Dodecahedron"}, 
   PolyhedronData[]},
  Initialization :> (poly := "Dodecahedron")],
 30]
```

Thank you  !

Comment: I moved all of `A16[poly_] :=`...`reg =`... inside the `Manipulate[` and before the `Show` and it seemed to work for me, at least until I chose tetrahedron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `A16` as the 16th vertex coordinate. However, for polyhedrons with fewer than 16 vertices that is undefined. Similarly for A7. I redefined these as the last and the "middle" vertices.

```
Manipulate[
 vc = PolyhedronData[poly, "VertexCoordinates"];
 Alast = Last@vc;
 Amid = vc[[Floor[(Length[vc]-1)/2]]];
 S1 = Sphere[Alast, r1];
 Spoly = PolyhedronData[poly, "Circumsphere"];
 polyw = PolyhedronData[poly];
 A167 = RegionIntersection[
    HalfLine[{0, 0, 0}, Alast + Amid],
    Spoly] // FullSimplify;
 C16 = RegionIntersection[S1, Spoly];
 reg = Region[A167];
 Show[
  reg,
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[o], S1, Spoly}], polyw],
 {{r1, 0.1, Subscript["Radius", 1]}, 0, 3, 0.1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{o, 0.1, "Opacity"}, 0, 1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{poly, "Dodecahedron", "Polyhedron"}, PolyhedronData[]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have another problem, when I open this file, Mathematica "evaluate" continually , the Output cell has a bold line down the whole height of the cell bracket ! You can see this screen capture :  https://photos.app.goo.gl/h2M6MiRVerM4L8KL9 . I don't know why ! Could you help me ?

Comment: Once evaluated, the `Manipulate` is continuously monitoring the controls so that it can respond ("The output is very much like a small applet or widget: it is not just a static result, it is a running program you can interact with."). If you no longer want it to monitor for activity,  either `Abort` the evaluation or disable `Dynamic Updating` from the `Evaluation` menu.